# How could I run multiple functions on csv files, then write the results to a new csv file in r?

Tags: r, csv

I am new to r and have created multiple csv files that contain 25 columbs and 25 rows. I have 10 functions i want to apply to these csv files, then i want to write each of the results to a new csv file. I have tried searching but can not find a useful method if anyone is able to provide some help or tips.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This involves a number of different design patterns, typically solved like this in R (based on your rather limited description):

```r
all.your.csv.files <- dir( "some/directory/", full.names=TRUE, pattern="\\.csv$" )

for( csv.file in all.your.cvs.files ) {

    x <- read.csv( csv.file )

    for( func_i in list.of.your.ten.functions ) {
        x <- func_i( x )
    }

    new.filename <- generate.new.filename()

    write.csv( x, new.filename )

}
```

voila! problem solved.